# C, why does printf add a "D" after a single digit long?

Tags: c, printf, long-integer

I'm working through the K&R C book and one of the example programs is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    long nc;

    nc = 0;
    while (getchar() != EOF) {
        ++nc;
    }
    printf("%ld", nc);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this program, it mostly behaves as I expect. So for an input like `This is a sentence`, it prints `19`.

However, if I input anything under 10 characters (including EOF), there is a capital `D` appended to the output number.

E.g. for input `hello`, the output is `6D`.

Why is there a `D` appended to an integer value and what does it mean?

Note: This occurs with `cc`, `gcc` and `clang`.

Comment: What is your prompt?  That is,  what shows on the next line if you just remove the `printf`?

Comment: No the output is 6, it is not 6D.

Comment: I see, my bad. Without `printf`, the next line has `^D`, because that's how I'm inputting EOF. If I change the `printf` line to `printf("\n%ld", nc);` then the number correctly displays on the line after `^D`.

Comment: This program will result in UB when the input is longer than `LONG_MAX`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that `D` is part of the `^D` that gets printed to the console when I input an EOF (`control` + `D` on Unix). Because there is no `\n` at the start of the `printf` statement, a single-digit number will overwrite the `^`, while a double-digit number will overwrite the entire `^D`, which is what gave the impression of some weird behaviour.

Comment: Click the accept checkmark to mark the question as satisfied.

Comment: I can only accept the answer in 2 days, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

What version of gcc are you using? I ran the exact same code using gcc and it runs fine. Maybe it's an artifact left over by your terminal where it's trying to print the Ctrl-D for end of file

[image]

Comment: This is asking for more details as opposed to shedding light on the question.  More a good comment then anything else. ( Question marks and words such as  maybe are why I am commenting.)

Comment: I'm on macOS, so it's actually `clang`, at version 12.0.0. It seems Command Prompt behaves differently than macOS terminals. My terminal prints `^D` when I press `control` + `D`.